# How to mimic selecting e.target when only a Jquery object is available?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-selectors, target

Odd...

I'm listening for an event like so:

```
$(document).on('some_event', 'div:jqmData(role="page")', function(e){
   console.log( e.target )
   })
```

In my console, I'm getting "hardcoded" HTML, like so:

```
<div id="profile" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-header-fixed" data-role="page" data-url="some_url" data-external-page="true" tabindex="0">
```

I need to replicate this selection from another function in which I don't have e.target available. Instead I have the whole page element, which consoles as an object:

```
[div#profile.ui-page]
```

**Question:**
I'm missing some words here... how do I select the same way as e.target???

Comment: Separately: Rather than relying on `console.log`, set a breakpoint and explore your data interactively in the debugger. Much more useful.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - DOM element... I wasn't sure what I was looking for myself. I need to get the DOM element from a Jquery object, the object being a page.

Comment: Breakpoints in Firebug you mean? Never tried...

Comment: @ frequent: Yes, Firebug, or the built-in tools in Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE8+, ...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: do you want to make your [0] an answer, so I can check. That worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like when you say you have a "whole page object," you have a jQuery object wrapped around the DOM element. To access the raw DOM element, you index into the jQuery object (which is array-like), e.g., the first matched element in the jQuery object is at `[0]`.

So:

```
var rawElement = pageObject[0];
```